# Select an option in custom dropdown using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select an option from the DropDown using selenium java. I have also tried many solutions. The country element is found when executing XPath in FirePath but not finding while running script.

Selenium Code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='selectize-input items not-full has-options']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);

    String countryXpath = "//*[@class='select-item']/following::span[text()='India']";
    System.out.println(countryXpath);
    WebElement countryName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(countryXpath));

    ScrollHelper.ScrollHorizontalUpToVisibilityOfElement(countryName);
    countryName.click();
```

HTML Code:

```
<select class="selectized isfocused parsley-error" name="Country" data-input-parsley="" data-parsley-trigger="change input" data-parsley-required-message="This field should not empty" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-group="country-select" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;" data-parsley-id="17">
    <option value="" selected="selected"/>
</select>
<div class="selectize-control single">
    <div class="selectize-input items has-options not-full focus input-active dropdown-active">
        <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" style="width: 100%; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;" placeholder="" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="selectize-dropdown single" style="display: block; visibility: visible; width: 413px; top: 32px; left: 0px;">
    <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
    <div class="select-item" data-selectable="" data-value="6">
        <div class="select-option">
            <span class="text">   Australia </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-item" data-selectable="" data-value="2">
        <div class="select-option">
            <span class="text">   Canada </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-item" data-selectable="" data-value="21">
        <div class="select-option">
            <span class="text">   China </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-item" data-selectable="" data-value="22">
        <div class="select-option">
            <span class="text">   India </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-item" data-selectable="" data-value="25">
        <div class="select-option">
            <span class="text">   USA </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: which country you wanna select ?

Comment: Can you update the question with a bit more of the `outerHTML` to include the element with text as **Country of residence**?

Comment: actually, I want to select a country name is 'Singapore' which is at end of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to click on Country of residence , then you have to **scroll down** little bit and then this code might work for you :

```
List<WebElement> countries = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='select-option']>span"));
for(WebElement country : countries){
if(country.getText().trim().equals("Singapore"))
country.click();
}
```

For scroll down if you are facing any issue, then please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

In Html, span text has spaces before country name

```
  <span class="text">   India </span>
```

Update the xpath as

```
String countryXpath = "//*[@class='select-item']/following::span[contains(text(), 'India')]";
```

Above mentioned xpath will check if the text of the span contains India

Answer (score 0):

Try using this xpath to click on element:

```
"//span[contains(text(), 'India')]"
```

Let me know if it works.